# nginx reverse proxy does not sends the packages

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am having problems configuring docker compose, being more specific in the nginx configuration since when I want to consume the API it returns the following

running

> docker logs webserver-callservices

> [01/May/2023:19:41:53 +0000]
> "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03d\x1F\xC3\x01\x8D\xEF\xADz-\xD2Me\xA1\x01\x09Rbd\x93\xED\xCA\xEB\xD6"
> 400 157 "-" "-"

But running

> docker logs callservicebackend-backendcallservices-1

I get

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system
> checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). May 01, 2023 -
> 17:01:54 Django version 3.0, using settings 'callservices.settings'
> Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C.

From what I understand there is a problem in the nginx configuration

this is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  webservercallservices:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver-callservices
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backendcallservices
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./Dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt 
    networks:
      app-network:

  backendcallservices:
    build:
      context: ./Dockerfiles/python
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c 'python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - databasecallservices
      - redis
    networks:
      app-network:


  celery:
    build:
      context: ./Dockerfiles/python
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A callservices worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    depends_on:
      - databasecallservices
      - redis
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    networks:
      app-network:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      app-network:

  databasecallservices:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      app-network:

networks:
  app-network:
```

This is the config of nginx

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    index index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backendcallservices:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```